# jq-solaris binary is responding with error

Tags: jq

OS Oracle Solaris 11.3 SPARC

Downloaded jq-solaris11-64 from https://github.com/stedolan/jq/releases/download/jq-1.4/jq-solaris11-64, any command with this binary is throwing error:

-ksh: ./jq: ./jq: cannot execute [Invalid argument]

Tried linux compatible binary on linux OS, it worked

./jq --version

Error message: -ksh: ./jq: ./jq: cannot execute [Invalid argument]

Comment: Just a shot it the dark but are you running on a 64-bit kernel? Try the 32-bit binaries.

Comment: I did tried 32bit binary and got same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compiled sourcecode on solaris host to generate jq binary